# Finding equation of tangent plane to the surface $f(x, y, z)=x^2+2y^2-3z^2$ at P(2, -1, 1)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, surfaces

$z-z_0=f_x()(x-x_0)+f_y()(y-y_0)$

$f_x=2x,f_y=4y$

$z-1=4(x-2)-4(y+1)$

$z=4x-4y-5$

Can someone tell me if this is right? Going over old problems I got wrong.

Comment: The constant should be -11 as in $z=4x-4y-11$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the gradient is always normal to the surface. Therefore, if you want a tangent plane at a point $\vec p$ you use the fact that the dot product of orthogonal vectors is zero to get:
$$\nabla f \cdot (\vec {x}-\vec p)=0$$ 
As the equation of the plane tangent to surface $f$ at point $\vec p$
In your case, evaluate
$$\nabla f=(2x,4y,-6z)$$
At $(2,-1,1)$ to get $(4,-4,-6)$ and plug into the above equation to get
$$(4,-4,-6)\cdot (x-2,y+1,z-1)=0$$

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. Never seen it done with the gradient before. Only ever had the equation I used above.

Comment: Using the gradient is just an easier way to use your equation, it is easier to remember and more systematic